# send data to new screen flutter

Tags: android, mobile, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to save the name and id to the different elements of my list for send the data to the new screen.

How do ?

I watch with the Shared Preferences but we can't with a list.
In my code, i need to save only the element who toggle is true.

Seriously, this screen upset me today ahah

Explain to me how i can do recup the result and i can send for my next page, next screen

My Theme model :

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Theme {
  int id;
  String name;


  Theme({this.id, this.name});

  factory Theme.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Theme(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
    );
  }

  Future<List<Theme>> getThemes() async {
    String url = 'http://10.0.2.2:3000/v1/api/theme';
    final response =
        await http.get(url, headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List themesList = jsonDecode(response.body);
      List<Theme> themes = [];
      for (var themeMap in themesList) {
        themes.add(Theme.fromJson(themeMap));

      }
      return themes;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load themes');
    }
  }
}
```

My Theme screen :

```
class _ThemePage extends State<ThemePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: Text("Blackbox"),
        leading: Image.asset(
          'assets/img/logo_ineat.png',
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
          height: 32,
        ),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
                child: new Text('Sélection du profil',
                    style: new TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter),
            new Flexible(
              child: new Container(
                child: new FutureBuilder<List<t.Theme>>(
                    future: t.Theme().getThemes(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        if (snapshot.data != null) {
                          return new Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Expanded(
                                child: new ListView.builder(
                                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                                    return ThemeListViewItem(
                                        title: snapshot.data[index].name);
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        }
                      } else {
                        new Text("Loading...");
                        return new CircularProgressIndicator();
                      }
                    }),
              ),
            ),
            new Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
              child: new RaisedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {
                  /*Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Technologies()));*/
                },
                label: Text('Suivant'),
                icon: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ThemeListViewItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const ThemeListViewItem({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ThemeListViewItemState createState() => _ThemeListViewItemState();
}

class _ThemeListViewItemState extends State<ThemeListViewItem> {
  bool isSwitched = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: new Text(widget.title),
      trailing: new Switch(
        value: isSwitched,
        activeColor: Colors.pink,
        activeTrackColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() async {
            isSwitched = value;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT :

Theme model :

```
  Future<String> getThemeId() async {
prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
return prefs.getString(_kThemeId) ?? 'id';
```

}

Future setThemeId(int id) async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

```
return prefs.setInt(_kThemeId, id);
```

}

Techno model :

```
Future<List<Technology>> getTechnologies() async {

    String idTheme = theme.getThemeId().toString();
    String url = 'http://10.0.2.2:3000/v1/api/theme/${idTheme}/technology';
    final response =
        await http.get(url, headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List technosList = jsonDecode(response.body);
      List<Technology> technos = [];
      for (var technoMap in technosList) {
        technos.add(Technology.fromJson(technoMap));
      }
      return technos;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load technos');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how i can get the line who changed when i click on my next button ?
I need to recup the differents lines who changed toggle = true for the next view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments here you can find everything you need to pass the params via `Navigator`. I believe that in your case you only need to pass the parameters while redirecting and there is no need to use SharedPreferences.

The 4th point in the link should be very useful for you, but I recommend reading the whole page because it described the solution from the very beginning.

Comment: I did differents shared preferences methods and i call this. I check your link. Thank you for your answer !

Comment: i edited the post @Patryk. How i can recup my id theme when i saved it in shared preferences thanks to my method in theme model class. I can't when i call it in my url